# RPLIDAR A2M8- Laser intensity values

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am subscribing to the Slamtech RPLIDAR'S intensity values but the values are either 0 or 47...I looked into the driver's code of the RPLIDAR in which the values of 0 and 47 are hard coded. I want real time intensity values instead of hardcoded values. Is there any way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337728/rplidar-a2m8--laser-intensity-values/) by [elemecrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/41195/elemecrobots/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

as i see in the protokoll spec of the scanner has no intensity output

https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf2/rpk-02-communication-protocol.pdf

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elemecrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/41195/elemecrobots/) on 2019-11-15**:
I see..any other way i can get the intensity values by writing some piece of code in the driver part of the RPLIDAR? Or any other version of Slamtech RPLIDAR which has intensity value function?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-17**:
I think, as this is the Protokoll between the sensors and Host , you are not able to change this behavior.

**Comment by [elemecrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/41195/elemecrobots/) on 2019-11-18**:
Do you know any other LIDAR which can output intensity values as well and is in the range of 400 -600 dollars?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-18**:
you may try this
LDS-01 360 Laser Distance Sensor
if you look at the driver you see the data is read out from the sensor stream
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/hls_lfcd_lds_driver/blob/master/src/hlds_laser_publisher.cpp
at line

**Comment by [elemecrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/41195/elemecrobots/) on 2019-11-18**:
Thanks a lot...any lidar with brushless motors? This one has a band attached

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-20**:
you may look at he
Sweep V1 360 it hast in the data stream 1byte for SignalStrenght

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-20**:
i fond the G4 from EAI YDLIDAR, it has an brushless motor and deliver the intensity values
http://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/NktoWf0y

and there is also a G6 http://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/nezGEejW

**Comment by [elemecrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/41195/elemecrobots/) on 2020-01-20**:
Hi, sorry for the late reply..are you sure G4 from EAI provides intensity values because I just checked the datasheet and it says that intensity values are fixed to false